# Wifi obd-II with flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, obd-ii

I want to develop an application to get data sent from an OBD-2 device trought wifi. I've seen similar app doing so and I'm interested in replicating some of their functionalities. The port on which the device transmits the data is 35000, and the address is 192.168.0.10. Could someone help me figure out how to connect to device and read the data from it?

I didn't try anything yet but I've seen someone trying to do this with a Bluetooth OBD-2 device

Comment: I'm not sure whether this question is too broad. The fact that you talk to an OBD2-adapter is not really relevant here, since at the end of the day it's just a TCP connection. So you might want to read up on how to connect to a TCP server using Flutter.